# How can I create a base controller with two different Get endpoints that works with Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following base controller in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 API:

```
[Authorize]
    public abstract class BaseController<TDomain, TContext> : ODataController where TDomain : class, new()
    {            

        protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;    
        

        protected BaseController(DbContext dbContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            _dbContext = DbContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public IQueryable<TDomain> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Test"); 
            return _dbContext.Set<TDomain>();
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public TDomain Get(int key)
        {
            int id = key;
            return _dbContext.Set<TDomain>().Find(id);
        }           
    }
}
```

As you can see, this base controller is very simple at this time. Notice the two `Get` methods. One of them has no parameters and returns a list of whatever entity type is provided, while the other accepts an `Id` and only returns the record that matches that Id.

The problem I'm having is that I'm using Swagger, which requires me to decorate both methods with `[HttpGet]`. However, in doing so, when I attempt to hit an endpoint, I get the following error: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints`. The controllers that derive from my base controller are all generated via T4 templates. Is there a clever way to enable Swagger to work properly and avoid the above error? Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Specify in HttpGetAttribute different routes: `[HttpGet("")]` and `[HttpGet("/{key}")]`, for example

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter in the HttpGet attribute

`[HttpGet("{key"})]`